# Retrieving SQL Server data using pyodbc is returning unexpected data values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am learning Python and have written some code to retrieve data from a SQL Server table. The code is as follows:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
"Server=xxx"
"Database=xxx"
"uid=xxx"
"pwd=xxx"
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Dealers')

for row in cursor:
print(list(row))
```

This code works fine but the output, for some data types isn't what I expected. For example, I have a line of output that looks like this:

```
Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('83.360'), True, True, Decimal('0.000'), datetime.date(2017, 5, 31), True, 1, True, True, datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 31, 18, 28, 57, 686666)
```

Instead of something like Decimal('83.360'), how do I simply get 83.360? Same for the date/time values?

Comment: You could simply cast it as a float, but the float representation won't be 1:1 accurate. For datetime objects you can use the datetime `isoformat()` or `strftime()` methods.

Comment: @jordanm - If you want to write this up as an answer, and show how it would be done, I would vote it up and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal('83.360')` and `datetime.date(2017, 5, 31)` are the default *representations* (`repr()`) of a `Decimal` object and a `datetime.date` object. If you want "just 83.360 and 2017-05-31" then you can call `str()` on them (as opposed to `repr()`) and you will get a string representation of the value. Note however that

```py
x = str(Decimal('83.360'))
```

will result in x being a `str`, i.e., it will have lost its number-ness, so

```py
y = x + 1
```

results in an error ('TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'), not `84.360`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems your solution is to cast the value to a string after it's been generated. Is there a way I can simply prevent the default representation from occurring, or changing the default representation?

Comment: There may be a way to override the default representation – Python seems to be pretty flexible that way – but I don't know why you would want to. It's really only programmers that ever see the `repr()` of an object; when we present that value to the user  (e.g., on a web page or a report) the object gets converted to some sort of a string representation anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess I really don't need to. I just tried exporting the results of my SQL query using Pandas, and the results were as expected.